# Название групп голосов за и против не согласовано

Tags: дефект, предложение, статус-завершено, локализация

На вкладке "Активность" в профиле есть группа "Голоса" и подгруппы:

- голосовал за
- голос против

[image: голоса]

Хорошо, конечно, что кол-во букв совпадает, но наверное первое слово всё же должно быть в обоих случаях "голос". Тем более в резолюциях именно так написано.

При этом в таблице репутации ситуация диаметрально противоположная:

[image: репутация]